# Updating Elasticsearch 5.6 index type with new mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I'd like to add a new mapping to an index I already have, I'm trying with

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -X PUT http://localhost:9200/videos_development/_mapping/video -d '
"video":{
  "properties":{
    "id_lookup":"text"
   }
 }
'
```

but it's returning

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"not_x_content_exception","reason":"Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes"}],"type":"not_x_content_exception","reason":"Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes"},"status":500}%
```

and I really have no idea what it means...

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is malformed, you need opening and closing curly braces + you're also missing the `type` in the field definition:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -X PUT http://localhost:9200/videos_development/_mapping/video -d '{
 "video":{
   "properties":{
     "id_lookup": {
       "type": "text"
     }
   }
  }
}'
```